# How to check the current usage of FD(file descriptor) table in android application

Tags: java, android, file-descriptor

I want to check the usage of FD ( file descriptor) table of the current running process.This is to avoid error like this **To many file open**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

install busybox and use unix command lsof through a native implementation.

use a unix terminal and type man lsof for more details.

Comment: i need some java code to execute commands on shell from inside of the application. and want to read the response of the commands are are executed on shell.